# how can i initialize an stored procedures IN parameter to a default value?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

when this stored procedure executes without this parameter, stored procedure should use the default value and if this parameter is assigned to a value, stored procedure should execute by assigned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable, say `myVar`. Check if the parameter is null. If it is not null you assign it to `myVar` otherwise you assign the default value.

Comment: thats fine ...but My SP need 4 parameter,some times i am passing only 3 parameter
so that i need to assign that 4 he parameter value to null.otherwise at ask 4 th parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can't, that's why it's not mentioned in the documentation.